# Trying to mock a function with jest but jest calling original function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

As I am relatively new to unit testing, my primary objective is to employ function mocking, specifically for the `add()` function. But I have encountered difficulties in achieving this goal.

```
// math.js
export const add = (a, b) => {
    console.log("Original implementation");
    return a + b;
}

// myModule.js
import { add } from './math';

export const multiplyAndAdd = (a, b, c) => {
  const result = add(a, b);
  return result * c;
};


// myModule.test.js
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';
import * as math from '../math';
import { multiplyAndAdd } from '../myModule';

// Mock the 'add' function
jest.mock('../math', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('../math'), // Use the actual implementation
  add: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('multiplyAndAdd', () => {
  it('multiplies and adds using the original add function', () => {
        // Set up the mock implementation for 'add'
        math.add.mockImplementation((a, b) => {
        console.log("Fake calling...");
        return a + b;
    });

    // Call the function you want to test
    const result = multiplyAndAdd(2, 3, 4);

    // Assert the result
    expect(result).toBe(20);
  });
});
```

Error: `TypeError: math.add.mockImplementation is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

[Jest documentation recommends to use `__esModule: true` property](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename):

```
jest.mock('../math', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  ...jest.requireActual('../math'),
  add: jest.fn(),
}));
```

Comment: After incorporating the suggested changes, but the issue persists and same error.

Comment: @DosadoJr which version of Jest do you use? I use `27.4.7` and your code works without any changes.

Comment: **jest@29.7.0**

Comment: @DosadoJr I created [a project from your code](https://replit.com/@sergdenisov/Jest-test#tests/myModule.test.js) with `jest@29.7.0`, it also works well without any changes. You could fork and run it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an alternative you can try:

```
import * as math from '../math';

beforeEach(() => {
  // Spy on and mock only the add method
  jest.spyOn(math, 'add').mockImplementation((a, b) => a + b);
});

afterEach(() => {
  // Restore the original implementation after each test if needed
  jest.restoreAllMocks();
});
```

If you want to mock specific methods of an object or module exports while keeping the rest of the object’s original implementation, you can use jest.spyOn().

This approach lets you mock individual functions without affecting the rest of the module’s exports, providing more granular control over what is mocked.

Comment: I tried but seems i can't use "jest.spyOn()" since i got this new error : TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'add' of object '[object Module]'